# Why c# dictionary foreach loop USUALLY iterates in the same order as insertion

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach, hashtable

According to the common truth and many upvoted answers the C# `Dictionary` is internally implemented as `Hashtable`, which if I have a correct understanding means that:

1. the order in which `foreach` statement iterates over dictionary's items is unpredictable - because behind the scenes every key is being hashed and the index in underlying array is assigned according to this hash value.
2. If want to add let's say keys equal to `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` it shouldn't matter in which order we will do that, since the only thing that matters regarding the internal representation is the hash value of the key.

How is it then possible that if I add the same keys in different order the `foreach` loop executed after that addition iterates over the keys in the same order as they were added?

What magic implementation stays behind this behavior?

The code snippet I used for testing:

```
static int[] x =  { 3, 9, 5, 11, 12, 13, 2, 24, 137, 4, 1256, 67, 1, 125555 };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //to avoid any rehashing and collisions issues the capacity is manually set to a value >> than the number of stored items
    Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>(10000);

    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        dict.Add(x[i], x[i].ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Foreaching element of dict after inserting from left to right\n");

    foreach (var kvp in dict)//this displays items in exactly same order as they were added
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
    }

    dict.Clear();

    for (int i = x.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        dict.Add(x[i], x[i].ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Foreaching element of dict after inserting from right to left\n");

    foreach (var kvp in dict)//this displays items in exactly same order as they were added
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs

Comment: You are wrong.  A hash is always predictable in the forward direction (not reverse direction).

Comment: The current implementation has that side-effect (but the implementation could change at any time). As long as you don't remove items, they will be enumerated in the order they were added. Try removing some items and then adding some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is partially related with: [How the Dictionary is internally maintained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600606/how-the-dictionary-is-internally-maintained).

In short, internally there are few separate collections `keys`, `values`, `entries`, `buckets` which you can look up in source code to which @Owen Pauling already posted a [link](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs).

You should be mostly interested in `private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)` method which is called for `Add`.

In the context of your question the interesting part happening there is  calculation of index, which in your case comes down to `index = count;`. According to the index, values are added to the `entries` collection and a value is set for the proper bucket bin.

On the other hand, during the `for` loop the `Enumerator` implementation is used which initializes `index=0;` and (in the simple case) just increments it during `MoveNext` calls. This means that the iteration is done according to the `entries` collection. Hence, you can observe the same ordering during iteration as while insertion.

The flow might get also a bit more complicated if more than one entry falls into the same bucket but this is not the case in your example.

***NOTE:***

Be aware that the description above is true only for the case you are presenting. If you try do to some modifications to the dictionary the ordering will be modified due to a slightly different flow for index calculation. For example, if before displaying the keys you would put:

```
dict.Remove(12);
dict.Add(15, "15");
```

The newly added key would take place of the previously removed one since inside the `Insert` method you would fall into `if (freeCount > 0)` condition.

Additionally remember not to rely on the internal implementation since unless documented explicitly, it might change.