# Store Value in Nth position of a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I have a Dictionary in the format of `DICTIONARY<STRING,STRING>` and I have value of 5 elements in it. The Output that I need is, If I want to store a new element in dictionary, that will automatically stored in position of before last element. How can I do that?

Comment: Dictionary does not define any order for its elements. Pleas [edit] the post to clarify what is your actual goal and show sample with desired output.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600606/how-the-dictionary-is-internally-maintained this question to know how Dictionary is defined internally. If you mention your goal there might be alternative solutions. Dictionary is not intended to have any order.

Comment: [KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx) might do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you do not know how Dictionary works.
Dictionary is based on a hash function that has a number of indexes. Based on the key, the value is placed somewhere in the Dictionary.

For example, the Dictionary of 5 elements can be like this:

[0] -> "element1"

[1] ->

[2] ->

[3] -> "element2" "element5"

[4] -> "element3"

[5] -> "element4"

So based on this, it makes no sense to store something before the "last" element. There is no "last" element. In the example, `element5` is stored before `element4` which happens to be because of the hash function used by the Dictionary. If you iterate through the dictionary you will get different results than the order of insertions you did.

**EDIT**: If I understand correctly, you need some data-structure that you can call `instance[key]` and in the same time be able to iterate through as a list. Such data-structure cannot exist, because `key` is a string, and there is no way to make an expected order out of string keys. No matter what the hash function is, it will not work. In any hash-table (or Dictionary), if you add (key1/value1) then (key2/value2) you will **likely** get the same order of elements unless both keys key1 and key2 hash to the same table entry.

In short, you cannot just build up an algorithm based on the order of which items are stored in a Dictionary. The order depends on the hash function, and index table size.

Answer (score 1):

You may easily edit any item like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dic.Add("a", "A value");
dic.Add("b", "B value");
dic["a"] = "new A value";
```

If you want to use order and indexing then use List:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Key;
    public string Value;
}

    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    items.Add(new Item { Key = "a", Value = "A Value" });
    items.Add(new Item { Key = "b", Value ="B Value" });

    items[1] = new Item { Key = "c", Value = "C value" };
```

Of course in this case you can have duplicate keys that if it you want to avoid duplicate keys then you should check it yourself.

Comment: there was an error in the list part of my code. I just corrected it. please have a look at it.

Comment: An alternative solution for the problem. Good suggestion

Comment: @AmmarSalman thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dictate how it is stored internally in a dictionary. It is a hashtable underneath and hashtable works based on a hash.

Can you make your question more clear? If you are more concerned about where to store an element, you could use Arrays(if you are not worried about keys).